# Perl module that automatically detects time formats ? (and can convert)

Tags: perl, date, time, module

I am building some kind of an engine receiving data from different sources having different date formats (e.g. `MM-DD-YYYY`, `HH24:MM:SS MM/DD/YYYY`, `YYYY-MM-DD`, Epoch etc.) and I want to parse them all and transform these date/time formats to a defined one (e.g. only `YYYY-MM-DD` for example).

I was starting to code this and make a huge hash with many regex of the predefined formats that I would receive (about 20), but then I was thinking...

Do you know any module doing this detection automatically? I.e. when we don't specify the format as we do not know it.

Comment: maybe DateTime::Format::Flexible can do that, will try it

Comment: What should happen to `2012-02-03`? Is it 1328223600 or 1330642800?

Comment: [Date::Manip::Date](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Date-Manip/lib/Date/Manip/Date.pod) has `new Date::Manip::Date->parse(...)` that recognizes a wide range of formats, e.g. `->parse('today')`

Comment: +1 for Date::Manip but note that some formats are inherently ambiguous and cannot reliably be distinguished: 10/11/12

Comment: thanks gents, will try date::manip !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Date::Manip](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Date-Manip/lib/Date/Manip.pod) is one option:

```perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Date::Manip;

my $date = new Date::Manip::Date;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $error = $date->parse($_);
    die "Can't parse '$_': ${error}\n"
        if $error;
    print $date->printf("$_: %s %O\n");
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
today
yesterday
tomorrow
01-02-2019
01/02/2019
23:12:01 01/03/2019
2019-03-02
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
today: 1550354400 2019-02-17T00:00:00
yesterday: 1550268000 2019-02-16T00:00:00
tomorrow: 1550440800 2019-02-18T00:00:00
01-02-2019: 982688400 2001-02-20T19:00:00
01/02/2019: 1546380000 2019-01-02T00:00:00
23:12:01 01/03/2019: 1546549921 2019-01-03T23:12:01
2019-03-02: 1551477600 2019-03-02T00:00:00
```

Date formats can be ambiguous, f.ex. compare in the above example `01-02-2019` vs `01/02/2019`. Although the 2nd one looks OK, you have to ask is it `MM/DD/YYYY` (American, as it was parsed) or `DD/MM/YYYY` (European)?

Another thing you'll always need to consider: if the input format doesn't include a timezone, in which timezone do I need to interpret it?

Please do study the extensive [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Date-Manip/lib/Date/Manip.pod) for the gory details.

Comment: Even more amusingly.... `01-02-2019` was converted to `20th Feb, 2001, at 7pm` (being `[YY]YY-MM-DDHH:MM:SS` - an almost ISO 8601 Notation.

(parsing is never fun...)